# Do I still need to register for Remote Notifications to enable Silent Notifications in my app?

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to send silent notifications to my users (receive in background - not alert, sound or badge).
I checked the Remote Notifications option in Xcode's Background Modes.

My question is - do I still need to register for remote notifications using `[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`?
If so - what type should I use? None of them looks like "Silent Notifications":

- UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score -2):

Ya you can do it:

But ask your backend developer to sent notification like following empty sound file:

```
{
"aps" : {
     "sound" : "nothiong.cif"
}
}
```

It will display notification without sound.

Note: The sound file not must in App bundle.

Comment: Do I have to use registerForRemoteNotificationTypes?

Comment: Yes. You must do. else it will display default notification sound. [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
         registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
          UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
          UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

Comment: What is the purpose of the Capabilities->Background Modes->Remote Notifications section in Xcode then - if I still need to register for notifications?

Comment: This link explains everything: http://www.g8production.com/post/72656082173/ios7-multitasking-silent-notifications

Comment: Ya great. But I am still using empty file code for one of my project.