# How do you get the push token to use without registering for remotes silent notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, access-token, silentpush

Reading from [WWDC 2015 Session 720](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/720/?time=126) it says:

> Silent notifications are enabled by default.
>   The user does not need to give permission to your app to use them. You can start using them without asking the user for permission

My question is:

1. How do you get the **push token** to use without registering for remotes?
2. If I still have to register, **then what does "default" mean here?**

Does it mean that you don't have to prompt to register, but still you have to register under the hood upon app launch? Which likely means default was a very bad word to choose?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721269/do-i-still-need-to-register-for-remote-notifications-to-enable-silent-notificati) but it doesn't answer this.

Comment: [Here](http://www.g8production.com/post/72656082173/ios7-multitasking-silent-notifications) is your answer.

Comment: @iphonic The link doesn't provide an answer. Doesn't explain what default means. I made an edit to emphasize on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have to register for push notifications.
Just **don't** register the `UIUserNotificationTypeAlert` or `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` or `UIUserNotificationTypeSound` type to make it silent and so that the user doesn't get prompted to enable push notifications

Comment: can you explain what does the word "default" mean here then?

Answer (score 1):

The user doesn't need to give permission to your app so you can use them, but you still need the app to register for notifications in order to get a device token. 
Without registering there's no way you can get a device token, and without a device token there's no way you can send a notification to a device.

Comment: so the term default is very bad word to be used. rather it means you don't have to prompt the user, you can just register under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

Not. You still need to register for remote notifications. Although they're silent does not mean there not remote, right?

You register for remote notifications, obtain the token, send it to the server and then send a notification without sound to that token.

**EDIT**

To respond to your edit: YES, the term `default` *might* be misleading or read in a wrong ways.

Silent notifications may be enabled, but you don't have a way to send them to the device. I think they wrote in the the docs so you don't go to the Preferences app and search for the "Silent Notifications" toggle.
Sounds more like a end-user explanation.

So they are enabled, but you need the user-prompt (say: "register for notifications") to obtain the token.

**EDIT II**

Apple could have left out this paragraph entirely.

Comment: Does the term "default" mean the registration can happen without a prompt as in the initial launch we can get a token for silent notifications without user permission? Basically we don't need to do anything like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzAd5l.png).  We only need such a prompt, if we are showing (badge, banner, sound). Basically Pera's answer?

Comment: Yep – We answered all at the same time – correctly. Then you edited your question and unfortunately changed it's scope, yo our answers aren't correct anymore.

Comment: do you have an answer for what does default mean? It's implied in my question and I just edited since no one addressed it properly

Comment: Check out my own edit – I hope it's answer enough ;)

Comment: Are you sure that you need to prompt the user? The other 2 answers say you don't. You only need it if you wanna prompt something UI like a badge, alert, sound...

Comment: Where do you get the token from?

Comment: From a process the displays the prompt. And you can't send remote notifications without this token.

Comment: @you get it without prompting. just by calling `registerForRemoteNotifications()` you only get a prompt if you do : `application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)` Where your notifications are `let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]` ie you wanna disrupt the user

Comment: Did you test this on a real device? I'm presented with the prompt after calling `[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]`

Comment: You seem to be using Swift. It's incomplete and this looks like it's insecure too (???). Could you check if it's a bug in the Swift implementation?

Comment: Did you confirm the prompt already during development? You'll get this prompt only once the application was removed for 24h (Apple changed something about it, go check it). Once confirmed, you'll get the token without prompt unless you reinstall the app.

Comment: you got prompted without having any `application. registerUserNotificationSettings(YourSettings)`??? I'll have to test, but don't have device now. Will do later and post result

Comment: Yes. This would be the correct ways to do it. Unless, if I'm using the old, deprecated version without settings, I'm not getting a token from the system

Comment: So I just tested. when I only included: `registerForRemoteNotifications()` I **wasn't** prompted to anything. Only when I used `application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)` I got prompted.

Comment: Now the last question is _why_ you get the token when calling the "wrong" function (extra attention to the double quotes, as I don't have a clue on Swift). Did you read my comment with the 24h / reinstallation-thing? Could still that one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135889/discussion-between-honey-and-julian-f-weinert).